# How to map an object and then modify its parts with @Mapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I'm fairly new to Java, Spring and MapStruct, so I don't really know where else to look, but I need to modify a @Mapping I have on a project I'm working on without making it overly complicated.

Suppose I have two DTO's:

```
public class UserDTO {
   public String username;
   public int age;
   public List<Hobby> hobbies;
   public String street;
   public int houseNumber;
   public String city;
   public String country;
}
```

and a second one:

```
public class UserExportDTO {
   public String username;
   public int age;
   public List<Hobby> hobbies;
   public Address address;
}
```

with Address type containing all the above information on the address (street, houseNumber, city, country) and Hobby being some type along the lines of hobbyName and proficiency or something, doesn't really matter.

Now I need to map this UserDTO to some super-object containing the UserExportDTO like this:

```
@Mapping( target = "newUser", source = "user")
public abstract SomeSuperObjectContainingUserExportDTO transformDTOs(UserDTO user);
```

the real structure on the project is a tad bit more complicated and involves not just mapping this user, but also some objects on as well in this one mapping.
This, however, will not map the address. Mapping the whole object one to one would be too much of a hassle, since there's a list involved and mapping list is also a bit more complicated. Is there a way to map and object and then also specify how to map one of its inner parts? Something like:

```
@Mapping( target = "newUser", source="user")
@Mapping( target = "newUser.address.street", source = "user.street")
@Mapping( target = "newUser.address.houserNumber", source = "user.houseNumber")
@Mapping( target = "newUser.address.city", source = "user.city")
@Mapping( target = "newUser.address.country", source = "user.country")
public abstract SomeSuperObjectContainingUserExportDTO transformDTOs(UserDTO user);
```

What I just wrote doesn't dispose of the original entries of address, it just creates a new address object, so this doesn't seem right. But...is there something like a simplified way to map an object, and then further map its sub-object?

Comment: use small block and compose them: start writing a `Address map(UserDTO)` and see what happens